# Using multiple LaserScan

Tags: ros, sicklms, multiple, laserscan, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use two different laser scan on my Pioneer robot. The first is a Sick LMS100, the second a Sick TiM300. How can I integrate their scan data in a single ROS node?

In my launch file I call the two laser drivers, but in the main scan data overlap: in a cycle, I obtain the first laser scan data, in another cycle I obtain the second laser scan data and so on...

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37794/using-multiple-laserscan/) by [daddy88](https://answers.ros.org/users/2758/daddy88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would say it completely depends on your system configuration. Normally, it should not be a problem when both lasers publish their data on the same topic since the LaserScan message contains a header with a frame_id and a time stamp. Of course, this requires a valid TF tree and the laser drivers to be configured to use a different frame id for each scanner. Amcl, for instance, supports several lasers on one topic.

By using topic remapping, you can configure your laser scanners to publish on different topics. Have a look at [this question/answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/9248/how-do-you-remap-a-topic/) for more information on that.

Finally, if you don't want to use the LaserScan message but a point cloud, you can use the `laser_assembler` node as @weiin suggests in his answer. However, this solution won't work for amcl or any other node that requires a LaserScan message.

On our robot, we use two Hokuyo lasers for amcl. Both laser drivers publish on separate topics and in the amcl node, we relay both topics to amcl's input topic using [topic_tools](http://ros.org/wiki/topic_tools)' relay. That way, we can access the laser scans separately or, if needed, on one single topic.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Laser pipeline](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_pipeline) is what you need, in particular, the assembler.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4